# Loading UIWebView blocks scrollview animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, animation, uiwebview

I'm trying to load a web view with data during a scroll animation occurs. Animation call is like that:

```
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:aFrame animated:YES];
```

The problem is, if a web view load process overlaps with the scrollview animation, animation is stuttered, not a smooth animation occurs. It seems like load process is blocking main thread, so animation doesn't work as expected.

What can i do in order to solve this problem? In some posts people suggest to put webview as subview in the last part of

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView
```

method. But loaded data is not visible if i do like that.

Thanks for help.

EDIT 1:

@Vlad

This solution is not working i guess. I'm calling webview load like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
    [_webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
});
```

But I see that although loadHTMLString: baseURL: method is called in a non main thread,

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView
```

and

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView
```

methods are called in main thread. So this method didn't provide me an improvement.

Also as a detail, time passed between webViewDidStartLoad and webViewDidFinishLoad methods are nearly 0.3 secs.

What else to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try initiating the load request on a separate thread.
Easiest way to do that is using GCD.

Should this be your request:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:someURL];
```

A separate thread call would be something like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t workerQueue = dispatch_queue_create("QueueIdentifier", NULL);
dispatch_async(workerQueue, ^ {
    [yourWebView loadRequest:request];
});
dispatchRelease(workerQueue);
```

Using this should no longer block your UI thread as all the loading should be done in background.

Comment: remmeber to use __block for your ivar

Comment: Umm, i will try it tomorrow. I was thinking that any method of a UI component should be called in main thread.

Comment: @Vlad, i tried your solution but it does not working. Details are on my edit.

Comment: `loadRequest` already retrieves the data asynchronously so you don't need to call it on a separate thread.

Comment: maybe your web is not optimized for mobile, and the drawing on your web view takes up CPU/memory and that might cause the freezing UI. @murat, yes indeed you are right, the load is already asynchronous.

Comment: i will try to stop continuing load request, but I've faced with another problem. However I'll not give details here, because it's somewhat indifferent from this question. Details are here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/10111918](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111918/how-to-stop-uiwebview-loading-immediately)

Comment: is it necessary to create your own queue instead of using of ready background one?

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov you can use a ready background one. I think it should have the exact same effect, but it appears the suggestion I gave is not working :)