# How to stop UIWebView loading immediately

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

As ios documentation says, `[webView stopLoading]` method should be used in order to stop webview load task.

As far as I see, this methods runs asynchronously, and does NOT stop currently processing load request immediately.

However, I need a method which will force webview to immediately stop ongoing task, because loading part blocks the main thread, which could result in flicks on animations.

So, is there a way to succeed this?

Comment: have you found any solution ? I am also facing same problem

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
if (webText && webText.loading){
    [webText stopLoading];
}

webText.delegate=nil;


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@""];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webText loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: This does work to immediately stop, but shows a blank white page.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the UIWebView to download your html document directly.
Use async download mechanism like [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to get your html downloaded by a background thread. 
When you get the `requestFinished` with a content of your html then give it to the UIWebView.

Example from the ASIHTTPRequest's page how to create an asynchronous request:

```
- (IBAction)grabURLInBackground:(id)sender
{
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request startAsynchronous];
}     

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   // Use when fetching text data
   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
 
   // Use when fetching binary data
   NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
}     

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSError *error = [request error];
}
```

Use the `responseString` to your UIWebView's `loadHTMLString` method's parameter:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
[webView loadHTMLString:responseString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Your original URL string"]];
```

Comment: I'm already using `[webView loadHTMLString:responseString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Your original URL string"]];` method to load webview, html page is on local file system.

Comment: Did you mean "local file system" as iOS device local? Or you have a computer on your WiFi network (the same as your iOS device using) to provide your html content? What does your html do? Is it a simple page or something dynamic with Ajax or other java based framework?

Comment: Html is not gotten from network, it's already on device local. Html contains a long text content in it, and it's just a static html.

Comment: I believe some complex web pages won't be loaded with this method. E.g., if the web page, after partly loading, runs some javascript to load additional resources.